# localhost send an invalid response code igniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm just learning CI4 from Youtube "web programming unpas" on episode 9 insert data (its using indonesia language). Well I followed the course and tried to insert data. After insert data to database, it will be redirected to the index file.

So the error is showing localhost send an invalid response

Idk what's the problem

Here is the code

routes.php

```
$routes->get('/', 'pages::index');

$routes->get('/komik/create', 'komik::create');
$routes->get('/komik/(:segment)', 'komik::detail/$1');
```

controller/komik.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\komikmodel;

class komik extends BaseController

    {
         protected $komikmodel;
    
         public function __construct()
         {
              $this->komikmodel = new komikmodel();
         }
    
    
         public function index()
         {
                $data = [
                   'title' => 'Daftar Komik' ,
                   'komik' => $this->komikmodel->getkomik()
               
              ];
              return view('komik/index', $data);
         }
    
         public function detail($slug)
         {
              $data = [
                   'title' => 'Detail Komik',
                   'komik' => $this->komikmodel->getkomik($slug)
              ];
    
              if(empty($data['komik']))
              {
                   throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException('Judul Komik '. $slug. 'Tidak Ditemukan');
              }
    
              return view('komik/detail', $data);
         }
    
         public function create()
         {
              $data = [
                   'title' => 'Form Tambah Data Komik'
              ];
    
              return view('/komik/create', $data);
         }
    
         public function save()
         {
              $slug = url_title($this->request->getVar('judul'), '-', true);
    
              $this->komikmodel->save([
                   'judul' => $this->request->getVar('judul'),
                   'slug' => $slug,
                   'penulis' => $this->request->getVar('penulis'),
                   'penerbit' => $this->request->getVar('penerbit'),
                   'sampul' => $this->request->getVar('sampul')
              ]);
    
              session()->setFlashData('pesan', 'Data berhasil di tambahkan!');
    
              return redirect()->to('/komik');
         }
    }
```

[image: error message]

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: On which URL does it redirect you? Is it a valid one? Have you tried to remove the slash at the start of your "redirect to" function? Like this `return redirect()->to('komik');`? Also if you want to set flashdata with a redirection you can write it this way : `return redirect()->to('komik')->with('pesan', 'Data berhasil di tambahkan!');`

Comment: You need to share your router config too

Comment: @ViLar the url still same, at komik/save 
and already used without slashes, still not working

Comment: @mail2bapi updated, please check it

Comment: According to your route config file, you don't have any /komik route declared. You should add something similar to `$routes->get('/komik', 'komik::yourFunction');`

Comment: @ViLar hello, i wrote like this 
$routes->get('/komik', 'komik::index');

still not working